# PHP preg_match on own computer doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code:

```
$success = preg_match('/(.+(駅前)?駅) (\(([^線]+線)\) )?((([^線 ]+) )?(\d+[分時])?)/u', $m, $matches);
```

Example input text is

```
大正駅 (JR大阪環状線) ﾊﾞｽ 20分
```

This regex works on https://regex101.com/ and the code works on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/. However, when I run the PHP code on my own computer, it never gives me a match. `$matches` is an empty array, and `$success` is 0. Yes, the exact same code. I have verified that the regex is correct (using first link) and that the code itself works (using second link). However, it still refuses to work on my own PC.

OS is Arch Linux, running PHP 7.3.11, system locale is ja_JP.UTF-8 (which I don't think matters, but just in case)

Does anyone see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Your code works fine here on `PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.19.04.1`

Comment: What encoding did you actually save the script file that contains this code in? (And where does `$m` come from, does that gets its value assigned from within the same script, or some outside data source?)

Comment: Check that the bytes for `駅` etc. are actually the same in the regex and the string you're matching it against - there are multiple ways to write the same thing for none-ascii strings, which is a relatively common problem with regexes and utf8 strings.

Comment: Works on all supported versions on 3v4l.org https://3v4l.org/o4ADM

Comment: @04FS Sorry for not explaining. Yes, `$m` is where the input text is, and I have checked its values countless times and confirmed it to be what I expect.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I found the answer--it's using 0xA0 instead of 0x20 for space, and my regex was searching of 0x20 spaces. I documented how I figured out in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to find the problem.

First, I tried just the one-liner commented by Nick (3v4l.org/o4ADM) on my PC, and it works. (Of course it should. PHP can't be broken.)

So I figured out that it's the data I'm feeding `preg_match` that should be broken.

Normal `print`s and `echo`s were in vain--`$m` is always how it should be. Then I considered AD7six's comment,

> Check that the bytes for 駅 etc. are actually the same

so I looked carefully to check that the characters are all Japanese and no Chinese variants are there. And it's all Japanese, it's fine.

So what could it be?

I tried using PHP's `file_put_contents` to dump the variable to a file, and then typing the same text with my Japanese keyboard manually and saving them to another file. I opened Meld (a diff tool) and compared the two text and voila--the spaces on the text use a different codepoint than the usual half-width space (0x20). It uses 0xA0 instead, which is a "no-break space", apparently. What the heck.

Fortunately, a simple `$m = str_replace("\u{00A0}", " ", $m)` did the trick.

Thanks to everyone for leading me to the right answer!